# Aptana AngularJS support

Tags: angularjs, aptana

Is there any AngularJS support in Aptana Studio, plugin or any other solution?

I need code completion for AngularJS. For example, if I am in html and type `ng` I would like to get popup box from Aptana where I can choose `ng-click`.

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse

Just tested this plugin with Aptana Studio 3 (build: 3.4.2.201308081805) and seems to work (follow installation instructions on the site).

Comment: This plugin has dependency on JSDT, which can be added to Aptana, from "Help -> Install New Software" with this url: [https://bitbucket.org/nexj/updatesite/raw/default](https://bitbucket.org/nexj/updatesite/raw/default)

Comment: @Alireza +1 for pointing that out. The bitbucket URL is no longer available though, but you can download JSDT direct from the Eclipse updates sites e.g http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

Comment: The update site download.eclipse.org/releases/juno does not have anything called JSDT contained within it...

Answer (score 8):

Use the last version of Netbeans 7.3.1 with [this plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/40296) or [Netbeans Beta](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/74/)

[Reference](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/?intcmp=925655)

I use [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) with this plugins:

- https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package
- https://github.com/maxhoffmann/angular-snippets

Comment: BTW netbeans 7.4 beta comes up with in-built angular-js editor support
https://netbeans.org/community/releases/74/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is none. I searched thoroughly when I started using angularJS on a daily basis (I currently work almost exclusively with it, from 9h to 17h).

What I ended up doing is making the change to Sublime text, which has support given from one of the main teams working on extending angular - [the angular-ui team](https://github.com/angular-ui/AngularJS-sublime-package).

There is also WebStorm ([see here](http://blog.neil-fenton.com/2013/03/04/angularjs-and-linux/)), of which I have heard wonders, but haven't tried (it's pay-only) and NetBeans, as EpokK has mentioned in another answer - I hate NetBeans with a vengeance, but it is a purely personal preference thing.

Comment: Yes, WS is very good. I saw couple of videos which are tutorials for AngularJS.

Comment: I have one more question for you Tiago. Are you just working on Sublime text changes or you developing commercial application in a company. If it is second case can you say sometning about your impression about using AngularJS for commercial applications. Is it good for developing large enterprise applications? Do you use it as SPA aplication or use it in combination with another web framework which is not JavaScript(JSF,Play,...).

Comment: I use it as part of a team of developers, for which, as of now, I am the sole frontend developer (VS 4 people working with python for the backend). I work with services created on a per-case basis, which gives me flexibility to define what I need from them, and I can create extremelly complex solutions quite easily. AngularJS + Yeoman is a powerhorse for modular, large scale applications (I work in a University, creating apps for managing employee evaluations, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a suitable one but i may rank them as follow :

1. `WebStorm` (not free) though it has a real editor support
2. `Netbeans` the best free IDE till now for Java script editing but not as smart as you expect (navigation, refactoring, smart object detection are not as you will need)
3. `Aptana` good but with angular it will only provide js highlighting and lower smart editor
4. `Sublime Text` (not free)
5. `Idea IntelliJ Community Edition` (worst of them no event highlighting or code formatting for js), you'll need `Professional Edition` that is paid

If you can afford buy `WebStorm` or `PhpStorm` otherwise you may use `Netbeans` or `Sublime Text`

Comment: these days (MS CODE - ATOM) are great candidates